# OrientDB integration for ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, orientdb

What are the options to integrate `OrientDB` with Ruby on Rails 4 ? I have found many gems for `JRuby` but there is no active gem for `MRI Ruby`.

I need document database and graphdatabase, so `OrientDB` should be interesting for my project.

Answer (score 0):

This is a native Ruby client, though i don't think you can drop it directly into a rails app and work on it like mongoid, ActiveRecord, etc.

https://rubygems.org/gems/orient_db_client

Its 100% ruby so it should be compatible with MRI.

Answer (score 0):

We are using https://github.com/veny/orientdb4r in production, which doesn't require JRuby, and it's been pretty good so far. We only use the REST client, which is obviously going to be slower than any of the other ways of interacting with OrientDB. The gem offers a binary client as well, but I haven't used it, and I think it's still in development.